# Shadow index for Sentinel 2

Tags: google-earth-engine

How is the shadow index calculated for Sentinel 2 imagery in Google Earth Engine? The following doesn't work:

```
var s2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200101T100319_20200101T100321_T32TQM')

var shadowIndex = s2
  .expression('(1 - blue) * (1 - green) * (1 - red)', {
    'blue': s2.select('B2'),
    'green': s2.select('B3'),
    'red': s2.select('B4'),
  })
  .pow(1/3)

Map.addLayer(s2, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', max: 3000, gamma: 1.5}, 'rgb')
Map.addLayer(shadowIndex, {max: 10000}, 'shadowIndex')
Map.setCenter(12.492289, 41.890117, 14)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3400a9c967ef320506632a8cc7d1499a

Answer (score 1):

Sentinel 2 imagery in EE has been scaled by 10000, so `1 - bandName` will not work. You either have to divide your image with 10000 before doing the calculation, giving you an index between 0 and 1:

```
var s2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200101T100319_20200101T100321_T32TQM')
  .divide(10000)
```

Or you do `10000 - bandName`, giving you an index between 0 and 10000:

```
var shadowIndex = s2
  .expression('(10000 - blue) * (10000 - green) * (10000 - red)', {
    'blue': s2.select('B2'),
    'green': s2.select('B3'),
    'red': s2.select('B4'),
  })
  .pow(1/3)
  .uint16()
```

Here's a complete script without scaling the image: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f493e8cb7762d532ccdf69b15924469f